# How to compare and remove similar rows from JSON array?

Tags: javascript, json

Let's say there are two variables: `a` and `b`. The JavaScript code should compare the two variables and produce the `result` by removing the similar data.

> Similar data means: `a` and `b` both have values: 202, 203, 204, 205.

```
var a = [{'pID': 200},{'pID': 201},{'pID': 202},{'pID': 203},{'pID': 204},{'pID': 205}];
var b = [{'fID': 202},{'fID': 203},{'fID': 204},{'fID': 205}];
result = [{'ID': 200}, {'ID': 201}];
```

How should I do it? The two variable have some similar data but different key names. Please correct me if I have done any mistake in naming anything.

> JSON array **`a`** is the main variable for data source, i.e. It will have more data than JSON array **`b`**.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is very unspecific. What do you mean by similiar data?
Please edit the question and include information on what result you are expecting, what you have tried, and what did not work.

Comment: so you want what is there in `a` and not in `b`? or in `b` but not in `a`? or both (items are in only `a` and items are in only `b`) ?

Comment: [JSON](http://json.org) is a string which represents serialized data. if you have not a string, then you have not a JSON.

Comment: well **"JSON array a is the main variable for data source, i.e. It will have more data than JSON array b"** does not imply anything technically. is all data of `b` will be present in `a`, or you need those datas from `b` as well who are not in a?

Comment: what if `b` has a data `206`?

Comment: where do you get `ID` keys from?

Comment: @NinaScholz I guess that `ID` key he want to generate for the resultant object array

Comment: I get different IDs from different Web APIs, and `b` won't be having any other data apart from `a`, i.e. `b` is subset of `a`, so `b` won't be having `206`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess just a simple filter and map will work, first filter and then map it to result type. as you already know all items in `b` will be present in `a`

```
a.filter(aIt=>!b.find(bIt=>bIt.fID===aIt.pID)).map(res=>({'ID': res.pID}))
```

Here is an working example:

```js
var a = [{'pID': 200},{'pID': 201},{'pID': 202},{'pID': 203},{'pID': 204},{'pID': 205}];
var b = [{'fID': 202},{'fID': 203},{'fID': 204},{'fID': 205}];

var res = a.filter(aIt=>!b.find(bIt=>bIt.fID===aIt.pID)).map(res=>({'ID': res.pID}));

console.log(res);
```

Another solution with reduce will avoid that additional `map` to result type.

```
a.reduce((res, aIt)=>(!b.find(bIt=>bIt.fID===aIt.pID) && !res.push({ID: aIt.pID}) || res), []);
```

Here is an working example:

```js
var a = [{'pID': 200},{'pID': 201},{'pID': 202},{'pID': 203},{'pID': 204},{'pID': 205}];
var b = [{'fID': 202},{'fID': 203},{'fID': 204},{'fID': 205}];

var res = a.reduce((res, aIt)=>(!b.find(bIt=>bIt.fID===aIt.pID) && !res.push({ID: aIt.pID})  || res), []);

console.log(res)
```

Note: To filter out you can use `some` method as well as it will exactly return true or false (unlike the found object or undefined) with respect to find. Both will work, and will break when it needs to.

Comment: glad that helps to find the solution you want. I have edited the answer and added more, please check the answer.

Comment: How to learn the advanced features of javascript like you have used? (I am using JavaScript for 6 months)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest approach will be get the values from the object and then use `filter` to remove duplicates

```
var getVals = ( arr ) => arr.reduce( (a,b) => a.concat( Object.values( b ) ), [] );
var getIntersection = ( a, b ) => a.filter( item => b.indexOf( item ) == -1 );

var aAr = getVals(a); //get the values
var bAr = getVals(b);

var output = aAr.length > bAr.length ? 
         getIntersection(aAr, bAr) : getIntersection(bAr, aAr) ; //which ever array is bigger use that as the first parameter
```

**Demo**

```js
var a = [{
  'pID': 200
}, {
  'pID': 201
}, {
  'pID': 202
}, {
  'pID': 203
}, {
  'pID': 204
}, {
  'pID': 205
}];
var b = [{
  'fID': 202
}, {
  'fID': 203
}, {
  'fID': 204
}, {
  'fID': 205
}];
var getVals = (arr) => arr.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(Object.values(b)), []);
var getIntersection = (a, b) => a.filter(item => b.indexOf(item) == -1);

var aAr = getVals(a); //get the values
var bAr = getVals(b);
var output = aAr.length > bAr.length ?
  getIntersection(aAr, bAr) : getIntersection(bAr, aAr);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join both arrays and get the count of number of occurrences of values and then use `array#reduce` all those values whose count is 1.

```js
var a = [{'pID': 200}, {'pID': 201}, {'pID': 202}, {'pID': 203},{'pID': 204}, {'pID': 205}];    
var b = [{'fID': 202}, {'fID': 203}, {'fID': 204}, {'fID': 205}];

var grouped = a.concat(b).reduce((r, v) => {
  var val = Object.values(v)[0];
  r[val] = (r[val] || 0) + 1;
  return r;
},{});

var result = Object.keys(grouped).reduce((r,k) => {
  if(grouped[k] == 1)
    r.push({ID : k});
  return r;
},[]);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out the unwanted (repeated) values using the [Array Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method. I the proposed solution, we first start by getting all the values from `b` and then filter out the objects in `a` that have the same values.

```js
// data
var a = [{'pID': 200},{'pID': 201},{'pID': 202},{'pID': 203},{'pID': 204},{'pID': 205}];
var b = [{'fID': 202},{'fID': 203},{'fID': 204},{'fID': 205}];

// get the values of b
var bValues = b.map((element) => (element.fID));

// filter out the a element that have values in bValues
var result = a.filter((element) => {
    return (bValues.indexOf(element.pID) === -1);
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you, it really worked, I need to learn more about map() and filter(). Can you suggest any more functions like this? I am newbie to JavaScript.

Comment: You are welcome, I suggest you read about all of the `Array` methods [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). You can find them in the left panel list.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, you want only to check the keys which ends with `ID`, you could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and delete the values of the second array and build a new array with the values.

```js
var a = [{ pID: 200 }, { pID: 201 }, { pID: 202 }, { pID: 203 }, { pID: 204 }, { pID: 205 }],
    b = [{ fID: 202 }, { fID: 203 }, { fID: 204 }, { fID: 205 }],
    getValue = o => o[Object.keys(o).find(k => k.endsWith('ID'))],
    s = new Set(a.map(o => getValue(o))),
    result;

b.forEach(o => s.delete(getValue(o)));

result = Array.from(s, ID => ({ ID }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```